# Scala bazel Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: scala, bazel

I am trying to configure `bazel` with `scala`.

here is my BUILD file:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:scala.bzl", "scala_library", "scala_binary", "scala_test")

scala_binary(
    name = "Main",
    srcs = glob(["app/**/*.scala"]),
    resources = [],
    deps = [],
    main_class = "io.baku.sbzcp.Main",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
```

If I try to do: `bazel run //:Main` I get an error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class io.baku.sbzcp.Main

it will work fine if I will move scala files to scala folder, without package, and remove package name from main_class. Problem is when I want to keep them in package.

Any idea ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah I am blind :)
Wrong path in src
should be:

```
srcs = glob(["src/main/scala/**/*.scala"]),
```